# Fieldcontainer incorrectly displays in toolbar with label aligned top

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

FieldContainer doesn't show correctly when you put labelAlign: 'top'.

Find my Fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1c2s
I create a custom field which is base on field container.
If you resize the window to a smaller size, you'll see that the textfield will go above the fieldContiner.

Any idea on how to fix this? Any workaround?
I've tried several stuff but I'm struggling... I don't now where I can act to change this...
And I definitly need to fix this.

Thanks in advance

(for reference: Open bug in Sencha forum: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?311212-Fieldcontainer-incorrectly-displays-in-toolbar-with-label-aligned-top)

Comment: I remember that I reported that bug earlier (2014?). IIRC I didn't find a full workaround back then, but removed the vbox layout, which did the trick.

Comment: Yes... this will be an "easy" solution, but how can replace it? With what? (By the way this is `hbox` not `vbox`). And if I change the `vbox` in the container by `form` it doesn't take into account the `labelAlign: 'top'`

Comment: If you search in your fiddle for `vbox` (not `hbox`!) and remove the layout you find, you will see that, by pure magic, the `labelAlign` is correctly applied. But you will then have to find another way to get something like `align:'stretch'`, which is unsupported by `layout:'auto'`.

Comment: That said, I think Sencha is not sure whether the bug is with fieldcontainer or with box layout, which is why no one cares (both code owners stating "My code is clean" and waiting for the other one to clean up the mess).

Comment: Ok got it. But yes... needed something else for `align:'stretch'`. I'll make some try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sur I found the answer.
There is a mismatch between the build src and the doc!

If you check in your built source for file `src/layout/component/field/FieldContainer.js` you will notice that it doesn't correspond to the doc (and especially some method missing like `calculateOwnerHeightFromContentHeight`).

**note**: This has been fixed in ExtJs 6.2.0

Proposed override to fix this:

```
/**
 * Override to fix componentLayout wrong calculation of height when labelAlign='top'
 *
 * See post forum:
 * {@link https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?311212-Fieldcontainer-incorrectly-displays-in-toolbar-with-label-aligned-top}
 */
Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.layout.component.field.FieldContainer', {
    override: 'Ext.layout.component.field.FieldContainer',
    compatibility: [
        '6.0.0',
        '6.0.1',
        '6.0.2'
    ],

    /* Begin Definitions */

    calculateOwnerHeightFromContentHeight: function(ownerContext, contentHeight) {
        var h = this.callSuper([ownerContext, contentHeight]);
        return h + this.getHeightAdjustment();
    },

    calculateOwnerWidthFromContentWidth: function(ownerContext, contentWidth) {
        var w = this.callSuper([ownerContext, contentWidth]);
        return w + this.getWidthAdjustment();
    },

    measureContentHeight: function(ownerContext) {
        // since we are measuring the outer el, we have to wait for whatever is in our
        // container to be flushed to the DOM... especially for things like box layouts
        // that size the innerCt since that is all that will contribute to our size!
        return ownerContext.hasDomProp('containerLayoutDone') ? this.callSuper([ownerContext]) : NaN;
    },

    measureContentWidth: function(ownerContext) {
        // see measureContentHeight
        return ownerContext.hasDomProp('containerLayoutDone') ? this.callSuper([ownerContext]) : NaN;
    },

    publishInnerHeight: function(ownerContext, height) {
        height -= this.getHeightAdjustment();
        ownerContext.containerElContext.setHeight(height);
    },


    publishInnerWidth: function(ownerContext, width) {
        width -= this.getWidthAdjustment();
        ownerContext.containerElContext.setWidth(width);
    },

    privates: {
        getHeightAdjustment: function() {
            var owner = this.owner,
                h = 0;

            if (owner.labelAlign === 'top' && owner.hasVisibleLabel()) {
                h += owner.labelEl.getHeight();
            }

            if (owner.msgTarget === 'under' && owner.hasActiveError()) {
                h += owner.errorWrapEl.getHeight();
            }

            return h + owner.bodyEl.getPadding('tb');
        },

        getWidthAdjustment: function() {
            var owner = this.owner,
                w = 0;

            if (owner.labelAlign !== 'top' && owner.hasVisibleLabel()) {
                w += (owner.labelWidth + (owner.labelPad || 0));
            }

            if (owner.msgTarget === 'side' && owner.hasActiveError()) {
                w += owner.errorWrapEl.getWidth();
            }

            return w + owner.bodyEl.getPadding('lr');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bug indeed, but there is pretty easy way to make that work - just set `minHeight: 65` to your url field.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1caa

Comment: Thanks @krysztof for this workaround. Hovewever, this was a simple case for a more widther use case... I have FieldContainer which are far more complex and the height can change (on user action). And I don't know how to handle this right now...

Comment: Sizing seems to work, so the only problem is to copy `height` into `minHeight`. You can for example use `render` and `resize` handler to do so. Check out updated fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1caa

Comment: You're solution works... pretty well. It's not perfect. I have some FieldContainer that hide/show panels and the size is not well calculated if it show something and hide afterward, the size stay the "big one". In the other hand, I notice that it seems that this is not the right componentLayout which is used! If you take the field container with `Ext.getCmp`, go to `componentLayout.calculateOwnerHeightFromContentHeight` you see that it point to the method of layout `auto`... it seems to me that this is the cause...